# Set a selected audio file as ringtone

Tags: android, file, android-intent, uri, ringtone

I am developing an application: I am trying to set an audio file as a ringtone.
I saw many posts, but no one actually helped me, so I decided to ask this question.

I use this code when the Button is clicked:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent();  
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            intent.setType("audio/*");          
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Sound File"), Audio);
}
```

in `onActivityResult` I am trying to get the file path and then set the audio file as ringtone using the code below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Audio && requestCode==RESULT_OK) {


          Uri s1 = data.getData();
          String s = s1.getPath(); 


        if(s!=null){    

            try {
                k = new File(new URI(s)); //(File k;)
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Some Artist");
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                //Insert it into the database
                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
                Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                  MainActivity.this,
                  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                  newUri);   

        }

        }
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work.
I would appreciate your answers. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I saw many posts but anyone showed what i should actually have to do. So i decided to create this complete answer , in which i have the solution of my problem...

Here is my `MainActivity.java` which i used

```
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent1.setType("audio/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent1, "Choose Sound File"), 6);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 6) {
            Uri i = data.getData();  // getData
            String s = i.getPath(); // getPath
            File k = new File(s);  // set File from path
            if (s != null) {      // file.exists

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "ring");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k.length());
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
                    .getAbsolutePath());
                getContentResolver().delete(
                    uri,
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\""
                            + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
                Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

                try {
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                        MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                        newUri);
                } catch (Throwable t) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, its really important to add those permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for example if you don't add the permission to write external storage your app will crash like mine.. xD

**What you need:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

You can try my app on Google Play : [BackAtel Audio Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gr.backatel.volume)

Hope that helps.... my problem is now solved!! i hope that i solved your problem too :))

Comment: I can set the ringtone and notification etc.. but the name of the tone in setting is "Unknown Type" written there, and even the ringtone is not added in the default list of ringtones, how to solve this please.

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman to list in ringtone list you need to copy that file into ringtone folder.

Comment: Sorry but this code not working for me, why you need to WRITE_SETTINGS permission @noobProgrammer

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and couldn't find an answer anywhere.

This is the code i used.

```
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public class Content extends Activity {


int selectedSoundId;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content);

    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    final Resources res = getResources();

    //just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to back to you
    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.Button01, R.id.Button02, R.id.Button03, R.id.Button04, R.id.Button05, R.id.Button06,R.id.button1};
    final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.deargod, R.raw.donttalk, R.raw.lookat, R.raw.stop, R.raw.text,R.raw.john, R.raw.sherlock, };



    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {



            //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
            //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
            //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {

                if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];

                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    player.reset();

                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    };





    //set the same listener for every button ID, no need
    //to keep a reference to every button
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

        // new code to prevent crash is below.
        if(soundButton!= null)
        {
            selectedSoundId = soundIds[1];
        }

    }



}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
}

@Override   
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 

 if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}   
  else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
  else {return false;}
 return true; 
}

public void function1(int id){  

    if 
     (savering(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

    }
    public void function2(int id){   
     if 
     (savenot(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }
    }



//Save into Ring tone Folder


public boolean savering(int ressound){
    byte[] buffer=null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
    int size=50;

    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    String path="/sdcard/sounds/";
    String filename="Sherlock"+".mp3";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "SHRingtone");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Sherlock ");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);



     return true;

}

//Save in Notification Folder

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public boolean savenot(int ressound){
    byte[] buffer=null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
    int size=50;

    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    String path="/sdcard/sounds/";
    String filename="Sherlock"+".mp3";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "SHNotification");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "sherlock ");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);




    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);



 return true; 



}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setting audio as a ringtone is the same as setting tone in alarm heres the code:

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path+audioname );
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,  path+audioname );
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");

//new
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  
///new

// values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
// ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
//Insert it into the database
this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(path+audioname), values);
//RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Activity.this,
//        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+path+audioname
          + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

// sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+editText1)));
//Toast.makeText(this, "New Alarm Sound " + editText1 +format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

using this code it allows your sound to be put in specific sd card folders and 
then setting it as ringtone and alarmtone:

```
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
```

or you can follow a complete [tutorial](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-set-recorded-audio-as-alarm-tone.html) regarding this problem.