# I cannot set the audio file as ringtone for older version devices. The section I wrote for new android versions works fine

Tags: set, ringtone, ringtonemanager

Code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, k.getName());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
if (RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE == type) {
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
} else if (RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION == type) {
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
}
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE,k.length());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + """ + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
System.out.println("Uri string: "+uri.toString());  //Do you think the output I got here is normal? Output = content: // media / internal / audio / media
Uri newUri = setandsharejava.this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(setandsharejava.this,type,newUri);
```

k=File

The ringtone is set with the name I want but when playing it uses the default sound for android.

There is no error message.

Thank you for your interest.

Do titles I reviewed:
[How to set ringtone in Android from my activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity)
[Set a selected audio file as ringtone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765447/set-a-selected-audio-file-as-ringtone)
[How to set a file as a ringtone for Android 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255532/how-to-set-a-file-as-a-ringtone-for-android-10)
[Set a sound file as ringtone and notification programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420969/set-a-sound-file-as-ringtone-and-notification-programmatically-in-android)
[How can I change the ringtone in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182891/how-can-i-change-the-ringtone-in-android-programmatically)
[Set ringtone from res/raw folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645511/set-ringtone-from-res-raw-folder)
[How can I set a ringtone for an individual contact on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437922/how-can-i-set-a-ringtone-for-an-individual-contact-on-android)

and more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after trying hard.
The problem was that I was trying to get the audio file from the application's cache.
After burning the audio file to the sdcard partition it worked fine.